# how to check specific word(char*) in char** words like "add" and do addtion by using if statement

Tags: c

what I want to ask about is

something like this

```
char** words
int i =0;
while(words[i] != '\0'){
    if(words[i] == "add"){ 
        //do addition by previous value in words[i-1] and words[i-2] by atoi();

    }
}
```

while I tried to solve this question, I used several different functions like strstr(), strcmp()

but I think I did some wrong about that

I need some smart person's help as soon as possible

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Using `strcmp(words[i], "add") == 0` would be the correct comparison.  What you've written is virtually guaranteed never to execute the body of the `if` statement.  The comparison `words[i] != '\0'` is an aconventional way of writing `words[i] != NULL` or `words[i] != '\0'`; not precisely wrong, but misleading to all (especially you).

Comment: String handling is covered extensively in even the most remedial C text, online, hard-copy, or otherwise. You would do yourself a favor in the long run by [researching this first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182380/191340).

Comment: words[i] is equivalent to *(words + i) ?? which still is a pointer (address) wouldn't the comparison be wrong ??

Answer (score 2):

This statement won't compare your strings, but addresses of variables. Pointer `words[i]`  with "add" which is string literal of type `char[]`.

```
 if(words[i] == "add")
```

use `strcmp`

```
  if(strcmp(words[i],"add")==0)
```